# Struts2 property tag. Force to escape single quote

Tags: tags, struts2, escaping, quote

I have rather silly problem.
Struts2 property tag doesn't escape single quote (**'**). Such behavior breaks my JavaScript code. 
It does do escape double quote (**"**) using html entities, but not single quote (**'**).
Is there any possibility to force property tag to replace single quote with appropriate html entity?

Example, string replaced with html entities.
Отредактированное событие с кавычкой **"**

The same with single qoute:
Отредактированное событие с кавычкой **'**

Is there any possibility to overcome such difficulty using standard approach? I wouldn't like to write some custom code.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're in luck! By default, the tag only escapes HTML, but you can have it escape JavaScript too:

```
<s:property value="yourValue" escapeJavaScript="true"/>
```